# Compilation error using buildozer. NDK location issue

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I have buildozer installed but I can't compile an apk. I am on windows so I have an Ubuntu 64 bits VM with oracle VM.

I donwload and install again cython, and configure several previous errors to be able to use python_for_android.

When I try to run the `buildozer android debug` command I get the next result

```
    Welcome to the Buildozer Virtual Machine.
Please see ~/Desktop/README.txt for more information
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Kivy_apps/HelloKivy$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'ln -sf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android ./python-for-android'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/Kivy_apps/HelloKivy/.buildozer/android/platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/Kivy_apps/HelloKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Application requirements already installed, pass
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/Kivy_apps/HelloKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Clean and build python-for-android
# Run './distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/Kivy_apps/HelloKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
Check environment
SDK located at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
NDK located at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
NDK version is r9c
API level set to 14
Check NDK location
Check mandatory tools
Distribution will be located at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/dist/myapp
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
PATH is /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c:/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools:/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Leaving ARM environment
Read kivy recipe
Module kivy depend on pygame pyjnius android
Read pygame recipe
Module pygame depend on python sdl
Read pyjnius recipe
Module pyjnius depend on python sdl
Read android recipe
Module android depend on pygame
Read python recipe
Module python depend on hostpython
Read sdl recipe
Module sdl depend on python
Ignored python, already processed
Ignored sdl, already processed
Ignored pygame, already processed
Read hostpython recipe
Ignored python, already processed
Modules changed to hostpython python sdl pygame pyjnius android kivy
Pure-Python modules changed to 
Run get packages
Download package for hostpython
Module hostpython already downloaded
Download package for python
Module python already downloaded
Download package for sdl
No package for sdl
Download package for pygame
Module pygame already downloaded
Download package for pyjnius
Module pyjnius already downloaded
Download package for android
No package for android
Download package for kivy
Module kivy already downloaded
Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
Call prebuild_sdl
Call prebuild_pygame
Call prebuild_pyjnius
Call prebuild_android
Call prebuild_kivy
Run build
Skipped build_hostpython
Call build_python
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux3
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 

[...]

creating Modules/Setup
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile
./configure --host=arm-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu OPT= --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install --enable-shared --disable-toolbox-glue --disable-framework

[...]

cp: cannot stat ‘HOSTPYTHON=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython’: No such file or directory
First install (failing..)

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DNDEBUG   -I. -IInclude -I./Include  -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DPYTHONPATH='":plat-linux3:lib-tk:lib-old"' \
        -DPREFIX='"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install"' \
        -DEXEC_PREFIX='"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install"' \
        -DVERSION='"2.7"' \
        -DVPATH='""' \
        -o Modules/getpath.o ./Modules/getpath.c
# Substitution happens here, as the completely-expanded BINDIR
# is not available in configure
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/Python-ast.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
sed -e "s,@EXENAME@,/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python2.7," < ./Misc/python-config.in >python-config
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Misc/python.man \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/share/man/man1/python2.7.1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/Python.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/

[...]


/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/osdefs.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
rm -f libpython2.7.a
if test libpython2.7.so != libpython2.7.so; then \
        arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -shared -lm -Wl,-hlibpython2.7.so -o libpython2.7.so Modules/getbuildinfo.

[...]

        Modules/xmltok.o Modules/pyexpat.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib -lz    -ldl   -lm ; \
        ln -f libpython2.7.so libpython2.7.so; \
    else \
        arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -shared -lm -o libpython2.7.so Modules/getbuildinfo.o Parser/acceler.o P

[...]
        cStringIO.o  Modules/cPickle.o  Modules/zlibmodule.o  Modules/xmlparse.o Modules/xmlrole.o Modules/xmltok.o Modules/pyexpat.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib -lz    -ldl   -lm ; \
    fi
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/parsetok.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
arm-linux-androideabi-ar rc libpython2.7.a Modules/getbuildinfo.o
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/patchlevel.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install

[...]

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/weakrefobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pyconfig.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/


[...]

Modules/xmlparse.o Modules/xmlrole.o Modules/xmltok.o Modules/pyexpat.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o
arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib libpython2.7.a
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
            Modules/python.o \
            -L. -lpython2.7 -ldl  -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib -lz    -lm  
/usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python2.7
if test -f libpython2.7.so; then \
        if test -n "" ; then \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 555  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin; \
        else \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 555 libpython2.7.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/libpython2.7.so; \
            if test libpython2.7.so != libpython2.7.so; then \
                (cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib; ln -sf libpython2.7.so libpython2.7.so) \
            fi \
        fi; \
    else    true; \
    fi
if test -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python -o -h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python; \
    then rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python; \
    else true; \
    fi
(cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin; ln python2.7 python)
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python-config
(cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin; ln -s python2.7-config python-config)
test -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/pkgconfig || /usr/bin/install -c -d -m 755 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/pkgconfig
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/pkgconfig/python.pc
(cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/pkgconfig; ln -s python-2.7.pc python.pc)
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb            _curses           _curses_panel  
_sqlite3          _ssl              _tkinter       
bsddb185          bz2               dbm            
dl                gdbm              imageop        
linuxaudiodev     nis               ossaudiodev    
readline          spwd              sunaudiodev    
zlib                                               
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

running build_scripts
CC='arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm' LDSHARED='arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -shared -lm' OPT='-DNDEBUG ' \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -E ./setup.py install \
        --skip-build \
        --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install \
        --install-scripts=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin \
        --install-platlib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload \
        --root=/
Creating directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/test/test_tkinter

[...]

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7
copying build/scripts-2.7/2to3 -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/Bastion.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7

changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/pydoc to 775
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/Python-2.7.2-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/Python-2.7.2-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/ConfigParser.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/Cookie.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/DocXMLRPCServer.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/compileall.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7

[...]

/usr/bin/install -c ./Lib/plat-linux3/regen /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./LICENSE /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/LICENSE.txt
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -tt /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/compileall.py \
        -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 -f \
        -x 'bad_coding|badsyntax|site-packages|lib2to3/tests/data' \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 ...

Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py ...

[...]


Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py ...

[...]

PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/compileall.py \
        -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages -f \
        -x badsyntax /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
make: [libinstall] Error 1 (ignored)
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages ...


Second install.
/usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/python2.7
if test -f libpython2.7.so; then \
        if test -n "" ; then \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 555  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin; \
        else \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 555 libpython2.7.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/libpython2.7.so; \
            if test libpython2.7.so != libpython2.7.so; then \
                (cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib; ln -sf libpython2.7.so libpython2.7.so) \
            fi \
        fi; \
    else    true; \
    fi
# Substitution happens here, as the completely-expanded BINDIR
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/Python-ast.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/Python.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
# is not available in configure
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/abstract.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7

[...]

running build
running build_ext
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/descrobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/dictobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/dtoa.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7

[...]

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb            _curses           _curses_panel  
_sqlite3          _ssl              _tkinter       
bsddb185          bz2               dbm            
dl                gdbm              imageop        
linuxaudiodev     nis               ossaudiodev    
readline          spwd              sunaudiodev    
zlib                                               
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

running build_scripts
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/funcobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/genobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/intrcheck.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
CC='arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm' LDSHARED='arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -shared -lm' OPT='-DNDEBUG ' \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -E ./setup.py install \
        --skip-build \
        --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install \
        --install-scripts=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin \
        --install-platlib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload \
        --root=/


[...]

running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-2.7/2to3 -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/stringobject.h /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7
copying build/scripts-2.7/idle -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Lib/calendar.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7

changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/bin/pydoc to 775
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/Python-2.7.2-py2.7.egg-info

[...]

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./LICENSE /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/LICENSE.txt
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/Bastion.py ...

[...]

Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/compileall.py \
        -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages -f \
        -x badsyntax /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
make: [libinstall] Error 1 (ignored)
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages ...
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2: \
        /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t -c "import lib2to3.pygram, lib2to3.patcomp;lib2to3.patcomp.PatternCompiler()"
Leaving ARM environment
Call build_sdl
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
find: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/application/src/': No such file or directory
Android NDK: WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/application/Android.mk:application: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpython2.7    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/png/Android.mk:png: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/lib*.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/lib*.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/gdbserver /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/gdbserver /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/mips/gdb.setup /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/libs/x86/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : sdl <= SDL_pixels.c
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/objs/sdl/src/video/android/SDL_pixels.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/sdl -DANDROID -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/sdl/include -DSDL_JAVA_PACKAGE_PATH=org_renpy_android -DSDL_CURDIR_PATH=\"org.renpy.android\" -DSDL_TRACKBALL_KEYUP_DELAY=1 -DSDL_VIDEO_RENDER_RESIZE=0 -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_MOUSE=UNKNOWN -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_0=SPACE -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_1=RETURN -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_2=LCTRL -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_3=LALT -DSDL_ANDROID_KEYCODE_4=RETURN -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -I/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include -c  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/sdl/src/video/android/SDL_pixels.c -o /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/objs/sdl/src/video/android/SDL_pixels.o 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/jni/../jni/sdl/src/video/android/SDL_pixels.c:35:22: fatal error: SDL_blit.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-for-android/src/obj/local/armeabi/objs/sdl/src/video/android/SDL_pixels.o] Error 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have installed the ndk and the sdk but seems to be unreachable by the command on compilation.  I try to change and export the PATH to the NDK and the SDK but didn't work. May be I have a wrong config on the Android.mk or in other place.
I am try to use the default API level 14.

Comment: Probably neither of these things is the problem, post the full log.

Comment: inclement, the full log is too big to post it. could help a resume?